# A private data member changes (become empty) mysteriously somewhere

Tags: java, private, member

I have a public class named "**InvertedIndex**" which has two private data members:

```
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> invertedList;
private ArrayList<String> documents;
```

I have generated getter and setter functions for them. I have a function named "**buildFromTextFile**" which fills both of the data members, and I have another function called "**processQuery**". I wrote a test unit in class "**InvertedIndexTest**" for processQuery which is as follows:

```
@Test
public void testProcessQuery() throws IOException{
    InvertedIndex invertedIndex = new InvertedIndex();
    String query = "ryerson award";
    ArrayList<String> expectedResult = new ArrayList<String>();
    expectedResult.add("ryerson award ??..23847");
    invertedIndex.buildFromTextFile("input.tsv");
    ArrayList<String> result = processQuery(query, 5);
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedResult, result);        
}
```

In this function, in debugging mode, when the function "**buildFromTextFile**" is called, the code will go to the class "**InvertedIndex**" and fill the data members, so at the end of this function the data members has correct data in them. When the running comes back to this unit test function again if I watch **invertedIndex.getInvertedList().ToString()**, I can see that the data is still correct. Then the function **processQuery** is called, and when the running goes to the "**InvertedIndex**" class, and inside this function, the **invertedList().ToString()** is empty. It seems that all the data is lost somewhere, but I don't know where. I would appreciate your help.

This is the processQuery method:

```
public ArrayList<String> processQuery(String query, int k){
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> resultIds;
    String[] queryWords = query.split("\\W+");
    ArrayList<Integer> list1;
    resultIds = invertedList.get(queryWords[0]);
    for (int i = 1; i < queryWords.length; i++) {       
        list1 = invertedList.get(queryWords[i]);
        resultIds = intersect(list1, resultIds);
    }

    Collections.sort(resultIds);
    for (Integer item : resultIds) {
        result.add(documents.get(item));
    }
    return result;
}
```

resultIds is null when this line  runs:

```
resultIds = invertedList.get(queryWords[0]);
```

I put a breaking point at the very first line of **queryProcess** function, and both data members are empty.

Comment: Obviously - It is lost in processQuery method. We cannot say you more until you show us this method.

Comment: Shouldn't you be passing `invertedList` as an argument to `processQuery`? Where is `invertedList` defined?

Comment: +1 for using a debugger before posting here.

Comment: I don't understand.  Which class is `processQuery` in?  You seem to be using it from your test class, without specifying a reference to an `InvertedIndex` object.  And if it's in your test class, do you actually have a second copy of `invertedList` in there too?

Comment: I think the error is occurring in the intersect method. Can you show the code?

Comment: of course I don't have another copy there. Shouldn't it gives me an error when I use processQuery instead of invertedIndex.processQuery? I am not used to java, C# would definitely gives me a compile error. The test class is in another file, another folder. still ...

Comment: Yes, it should give you an error, unless you've either got two copies of the method, or one class extends the other; both of which would be wrong things to do.  I can only speculate on _which_ particular wrong thing you happened to do, but don't blame it on the language.  C# would do the same thing if you made the same mistake.

Comment: Yes you are right. I used a wizard to auto-generate a test class foe me, in eclipse, and it added an "extends" keyword on that class. Now I know it is not related to language, but since I tried to make them related, I couldn't find the problem, although it was a known concept, just different syntax. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More problems with your invertedList, I see. :-)

This is actually being caused by the exact same problem you had previously:
[Hashmap get function returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22489756/hashmap-get-function-returns-null)

Line

```
ArrayList<String> result = processQuery(query, 5);
```

Should read

```
ArrayList<String> result = invertedIndex.processQuery(query, 5);
```

Recommend moving all your tests to a completely separate file. That would save you these field reference headaches.

Comment: It is in a separate file, in a separate folder!!